# JavaScript double form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am new to JavaScript and I have been doing a university assignment based around HTML and JavaScript. In this assignment I was asked to create a number of forms to allows a person to register for some form of educational classes. I was asked to create the form using HTML and to validate the entries using only JavaScript.

What I have been struggling to figure out is how to validate more than one form input using one block of validation (if that is possible), I want to validate both the `firstname` and `familyname` inputs using only `validateForm`.

Here is a segment I have been testing out:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["nameform"]["firstname"].value;
            if (x == null || x == "") {
                alert("first name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="nameform" , action="demo_form.asp" , onsubmit="return validateForm()" , method="post">
<b>First name:</b> 
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <br>
<b>Family name:</b> 
        <input type="text" name="familyname">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
  var firstname=document.getElementById('txtfirstname');
  var familyname=document.getElementById('txtfamilyname');

   if (firstname.value=="")
       {
         alert("first name must be filled out");
         return false;
        }
  if (familyname.value=="")
     {
         alert("familyname must be filled out");
         return false;
     }

 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="nameform", action="demo_form.asp", onsubmit="return validateForm()", method="post">
<b>First name:</b> <input type="text" id="txtfirstname" name="firstname">
<br>
<b>Family name:</b> <input type="text" id="txtfamilyname" name="familyname">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check all inputs, store error messages (if any) and return false at the end if there is even one failure.

i.e.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["nameform"]["firstname"].value, errors = [];
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        errors.push("first name must be filled out");
    }
    x = document.forms["nameform"]["familyname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        errors.push("family name must be filled out");
    }
    if(errors.length > 0) { // check if there were any errors
        alert(errors.join("\n")); // alert all messages together
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply store it in multiple variables and have multiple if statements:

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        // name the variables appropriately
        var firstname = document.forms["nameform"]["firstname"].value;
        var familyname = document.forms["nameform"]["familyname"].value;
        // check if either of them are correct, if not alert and return false.
        if (firstname == null || firstname == "") {
            alert("first name must be filled out");
            return false;
        } else if (familyname == null || familyname == ""){
            alert("family name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The default for an unassigned boolean value is false. You should explicitly return true if all fields validate.

Comment: Thanks @ElPedro, I was wondering if it needed that whilst I was doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possibilities...

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["nameform"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("first name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    x=document.forms["nameform"]["lasttname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("last name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
</script>
```

will present an alert for each field as it fails validation and return true if all fields are OK.

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var errorString="";
    var x=document.forms["nameform"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        errorString+="first name must be filled out\n";
    }
    x=document.forms["nameform"]["lasttname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        errorString+="last name must be filled out\n";
    }
    if(errorString=="")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(errorString);
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

will return a single alert listing all of the fields that have failed validation.

In addition, I always like to use the focus() method on the first field that failed validation to put the cursor in the field that needs correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function validateForm() 
{
    var msg='';
    var flag=false;
        var x = document.forms["nameform"]["firstname"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") 
        {
            flag = true;
            msg = ' First Name '
        }
        x = document.forms["nameform"]["familyname"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") 
        {
            if(flag==true)
                msg = msg + 'And Family Name '
            else
                msg = msg +  ' Family Name ';
            flag = true;
        }
        if (flag==true) {
            msg = msg + " must be filled out";
        alert(msg);
        }
        return false;
}
```